# How to access instance fields from [UIHint] template in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have these fields in a model class:

```
[UIHint("CustomDDL")]
public AppVersion Version { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
```

How to access `Name` value from CustomDDL template?

Comment: you can use `ViewData`

Comment: I use the Model in grid, so there are many items and I cannot know which is the current one